# Configure Lotus Domino server to pull/fetch mail from external POP3 server

Tags: ibm-domino

I am looking to trial having a mailbox on a Domino server - prior to moving the whole domain over upon successful proof of concept.

The current environment has:

Mail hosted, available via POP3 or IMAP.
Domino users all send mail from one mailbox.
The Domino environment has been configured as follows:

All users share the same email file (as all emails must go from that one user).
There is a global domain document with a fictitious domain, ensuring that all email, including emails on the same domain, are routed via the SMTP server.
I have looked at two products to pull the emails in from the mailbox, and put them into the mail.box on the server for distribution. I need to be careful on the configuration here as I still want emails to be routed to the external provider.

My proof of concept will span 3 mailboxes, so the one alternative is to set up 3 clients, all configured to receive email and then replicate that onto the server. This is a little messy.

Anyone got any recommendations?

A

Comment: Yes - don't use POP3 like this. It wasn't designed for use as a server-to-server protocol, and because of this even the best POP3 adapter/plugin will be a gruesome hack , so you will see all kinds of odd little problems and reliability issues.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  The only reason I would is for a proof of concept.  the long term plan is to move all mail to route to the Domino server.  Have some stakeholders who want to see how it would work having mail on the Domino server (and available via an app I develop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the subject "Configure Lotus Domino server to receive POP mail from external source" you wish to collect emails via Lotus Domino from a external POP3 system right?

Then you could use the freeware here:
http://abdata.ch/POP3Collect.html

But I have problems to understand the other requirements you have.

Comment: Essentially I'm looking for a mailbox on the server which can receive POP email from another server, until I move all mail to the Domino server.  I'll check the link out as it looks quite interesting.

Comment: Thanks @BastianW - it works a treat, and does exactly what I want.  I have configured it to deliver the email to an internal only email address, and then used the Team Mailbox on OpenNTF to spoof who the mail is outbound from.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been useful to name the products you already tried.

In the Domino world, it's usually either POP3Collect, as Bastian already mentioned, or. if you are running on Linux, fetchmail or more modern getmail to collect mail from a POP3 server and deliver it to the Domino server via SMTP.

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with this setup and what your question exactly is. From what I gather, you are creating a mail loop, as you are fetching mails from the POP3 server, deliver them via SMTP to Domino, which is then delivering the mail via SMTP to the smarthost server.

What do you want to "proof" with this setup?

Comment: All I'm looking to do is get mail for a handful of accounts to come into Domino so that they can become part of a workflow.  Mail is currently not hosted by the domino server, and my long term plan is to move mail onto the domino server - however I need buy in from the stakeholders, hence the proof of concept. POP3Collect is great - it's working a treat.